# Get JSON nested values in python

Tags: python, json, nested

I'm 99% sure this has already been answered, but I'm a serious newbie and need your gental kindness.

Below is JSON I get through an API call

```
{
name: "dt_listings",
count: 10,
results: {
collection1: [
    {
    title: {
    text: "Human Anatomy and Physiology 10th",
    href: "http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780321927040"
    },
    isbn: {
    text: "9780321927040",
    href: "http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780321927040"
    }
} ]

import requests
import json
dt_raw = requests.get(dt_listings_url)
dt_json = dt_raw.json()
```

After this, is where my problems begin.  I can't seem to go to ['results'] and then to ['collection1'] then ['title'] to get the values of ['title']['text'] nor  ['isbn']['text']

Big request, if you use code sample to help, please use the names of the objects above so that i can follow (I'm having a serious brain freeze here!).  And yes, i have read many stackoverflow posts related and I'm still having a hard time with this.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `json.loads` to convert the returned JSON string to a dictionary and access it's fields ?

Comment: A proper JSON should have keys in double quotes. "name":"dt_listings"

Comment: You forgot to close `collection1`, you opened it with `[` but not closed it with `]` This is not a valid JSON. In addition, 2 more `}` missed

Comment: What happens when you try? What error do you get?

Comment: sorry, to clarify, the JSON is a sample of a much larger file

Answer (score 3):

Check your json, it has three things wrong

1. Key and values should be in **double quotes**.
2. For **collection** key closing **brakect ]** is missing.
3. ALso it is missing two closing **brakets }**.

Here is your proper json

```
 {
    "name": "dt_listings",
    "count": 10,
    "results": {
    "collection1": [
        {
         "title": {
         "text": "Human Anatomy and Physiology 10th",
         "href": "http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780321927040"
         },
         "isbn": {
         "text": "9780321927040",
         "href": "http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780321927040"
         }
       }
     ]
    }
  }
```

If your json is in proper format,check type of your json using
**type(dt_json)**

If type is **str**, do **json.loads(dt_json)** and then try **dt_json["results"]["collection1"][0]["title"]["text"]**

And if type is dict, then directly try **dt_json["results"]["collection1"][0]["title"]["text"]**

Comment: OP is using requests library so `dt_raw.json()` will automatically parse JSON response and return a dictionary instead of a string. So no need to check type and then call `json.loads`. Also `dt_raw.json()` will raise `ValueError` if response content was not valid. So if OP is getting past this line without exception then probably he is getting valid JSON.

Comment: this helps some.  the example JSON above is closed correctly and i just didnt copy/paste.  however i think you are on to something with checking the type.

Comment: Muhammand - you are 100% correct.  it is returning a dict.  going to try the dict suggestion above in a second

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use:

   dt_json["results"]["collection1"][0]["title"]["text"]
2. There is a closing square bracket missing ("] "), probably before the last closing curly bracket. This makes the value of dt_json["results"]["collection1"] a list which should be indexed by an integer.

Comment: 1 `]` and 2 `}` missed.

Comment: I assume that does not work if the keys are not quoted.  i didn't notice that and now am wondering why the source (not under my control) has the data formatted in this way

Answer (score 0):

**First**, **Dictionary** is not valid. **Keys** should be in **double quotes**.

**Second**, 
You have to check the **type** of **response** which you are getting via **API**.

Assume, you get your answer into **dt_json**. Check type of it using `type(dt_json)`.

If **type** is "**str**" then you have to **loads** that **dt_json** using json.loads(dt_json) and then you can **prase** it easily..

Comment: my debugger tells me that dt_json is a dict.  what next? :(

Comment: and now i want to ask kimonolabs, which is where i created the api, is returning a dict

Comment: @BruceBookman: Just valid your dictionary response [here](json.parser.online.fr). If it dictionary, then you can easily do iteration over it.  Please update your question with correct dict by which I can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "name": "dt_listings",
  "count": 10,
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Human Anatomy and Physiology 10th",
          "href": "http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780321927040"
        },
        "isbn": {
          "text": "9780321927040",
          "href": "http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780321927040"
        }
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```

I guess your data should be like above. There are some syntax errors in your json data.

If that's true:

```
import json

your_data = "{\n\"name\": \"dt_listings\",\n\"count\": 10,\n\"results\": {\n\"collection1\": [\n{\n    \"title\": {\n    \"text\": \"Human Anatomy and Physiology 10th\",\n    \"href\": \"http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780321927040\"\n    },\n    \"isbn\": {\n    \"text\": \"9780321927040\",\n    \"href\": \"http://www.directtextbook.com/isbn/9780321927040\"\n    }\n    }\n  ]\n} \n}\n"

structured_data = json.loads(your_data)

# then get the result:

print structured_data['results']['collection1'][0]['isbn']
```

Comment: unfortunately, that is how the data gets to me :(  not my data to format.  but i think i have been able to force it to a format like what you have in your_data.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone was super helpful.  The key issue is that dt_json is type dict.  So the code below works perfectly.

```
dt_raw = requests.get(dt_listings_url)
dt_json = dt_raw.json()
print dt_json["results"]["collection1"][0]["isbn"]["text"]
```